eBPF for changing block IO requests
Is it possible to use eBPF to intercept block I/O requests and modify them in Linux? For example, can I use eBPF to split a request for reading 10 MB of data from an SSD into 10 separate read requests, each for 1 MB of the original data? Additionally, can I use eBPF to add delays to block I/O requests (i.e., hold the request briefly before sending it to the driver)?

I do not think so, at least not at the moment. eBPF does not allow for writing to arbitrary memory to lets say modify arguments. Delaying execution is also not something eBPF can do. It can call its own code on a timer but not delay execution.
This would be a case where the kernel needs to add a new program type with these capabilities, allowing an eBPF program to match and pass a verdict. But not something that existing program types can do.
